# How to use dynamic color to ShadcnUI checkbox using TailwindCSS?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

So I have data that has the field called `colorHexCode` and I use this to render the color dynamically for each data. I'm trying to use this field on a checkbox for each data (checkbox component is from ShadcnUI).

By default looks something like this:

```js
<Checkbox className="w-4 h-4 data-[state=checked]:bg-red-500" />
```

What I'm trying to do:

```js
<Checkbox className={`w-4 h-4 data-[state=checked]:bg-[${data.colorHexCode}]`} />
```

Which I know won't work because TW basically doesnt support that, so the only way I know we can apply dynamic color is by using `style` parameter, but how can I apply it only when the checkbox is checked?

The only way I could think of right now, is to make the `Checbox` component controlled, and then conditionally renders it, but i'm just wondering if there's a better or simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with dynamically setting the background color of a checkbox using Tailwind CSS and template literals stems from how Tailwind's compiler operates. Tailwind CSS is designed for efficiency and, as part of its build process, it removes all unused classes from the final CSS bundle. This pruning process requires the full class name to be explicitly mentioned in the code. Since template literals dynamically generate class names, Tailwind's compiler can't predict these class names during build time and thus can't include them in the final CSS.

In your case, when you try to use template literals to inject a hex color code into a class name (e.g., `data-[state=checked]:bg-[${data.colorHexCode}]`), Tailwind's compiler cannot recognize this dynamic class name during the build process. As a result, the class doesn't exist in the final CSS, and therefore, doesn't apply the desired styles.

However, there is a neat solution that involves using CSS variables to dynamically set the background color. This method utilizes the ability of CSS variables to be defined inline and then referenced within your Tailwind CSS classes. Here's how you can apply it to your Checkbox component:

```
<Checkbox
  className="w-4 h-4 data-[state=checked]:bg-[var(--primary)]"
  style={{ "--primary": data.colorHexCode }}
/>
```

In this example, we define a CSS variable `--primary` inline within the style attribute. The value of `--primary` is set to the desired color hex code from your data. Then, in the className, we use Tailwind's arbitrary value syntax (`bg-[var(--primary)]`) to apply the `--primary` variable as the background color when the checkbox is checked (denoted by `data-[state=checked]`).

This approach combines the utility of Tailwind CSS with the flexibility of CSS variables, allowing you to dynamically change styles based on your component's state or props.

Comment: Just a quick question, when you set the `--primary` variable in style, does it apply globally, or is it isolated to the component it is being applied to?

Comment: @Owenn When you set a CSS variable in the style attribute of an HTML element, the scope of that variable is limited to the element itself and its child elements. It does not apply globally. If my response resolved your issue, I would be grateful if you could mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: It appears this post was in whole or in part created with AI tools. Please note that [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831) and read [Help Center: AI policy](/help/ai-policy).
It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Work of others without [attribution](/help/referencing) also constitutes plagiarism. __Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.__